# How to move queued caller into existing conference call

Tags: twilio

I've been working on twilio voice API. My use case is following:-
1. Customer calls come in and in case of no agent available move that call to queue. (Achieved the scenario).
2. Once the agent is free. I dial the agent using dial api and move him to conference as I need barge scenario on call. (Achieved the scenario ).
3. Now as agent waits in the conference room I want to move the customer waiting at queue to that specific conference so that agent could start talking to the customer. Need Help on that how to move a queued call to an existing conference.

I've tried twillio documentation and unable to search for relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To do this you need to [update the customer's call in flight using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call?code-sample=code-update-a-call-redirect-1&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x).

You'll need to store the incoming Call Sid so you can refer to the call later. Then you can update the call, sending it a new URL. That URL should contain the next TwiML you want the call to execute, in this case a `<Dial>` with `<Conference>` to connect them with your agent.

The code to update a call looks a bit like this (if you're using Node):

```
const accountSid = 'your_account_sid';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.calls(callSid)
  .update({ method: 'POST', url: newConferenceUrl })
  .then(call => console.log("Call redirected successfully"));
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: OK. noted. My agent joins conference and listen hold music. How to trigger dial.queue from here to connect to next customer in queue. i.e. should I directly server twiml for dial.queue at the time of outbound dial api call to agent (instead of moving agent to conference) and once they are connected I should take both to conference. Need your suggestion.

Comment: If you want to use a conference then you don't want to use `<Dial><Queue>`. You want to do what I suggest here, which is to update the customer's call to a new URL that points them into the conference where your agent is waiting.

Comment: I'm unable to fetch callSid for my use case. Is there any other approach you suggest. What if I call the agent (when he is available by using dial API) and at it's url serve twiml for dial.queue. In this my agent and customer are connected but now the issue is how to move both in conference. Need possible scenarios how to move them without disconnecting call.

Comment: Why can't you get the Call SID from the initial webhook?

Comment: Save sid of every call is overhead for me. 1. Call comes in from customer and en-queued.
2. When agent is available, use outbound dial API, serve twiml to dial  queue. My agent connects with first customer in queue.
3. Now want to move both to conference by using an api which changes  call in progress. One option in my mind is to use action attribute of agent  and move him to conference by sending conference name as param to webhook but I'm unable to find way for customer. I can do that at dial.enqueue by action attribute but no room name available at that time.  Need some suggestions on it.

Comment: If you don't want to store your currently active SIDs you could always request the call at the head of the queue using the [Queue resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/member-resource#read-multiple-member-resources). That way you could still use the above code to direct the call out of the queue into a conference. I don't see the point in using `<Dial><Queue>` and then going through the difficulty of moving callers from a direct connection to a conference. Check out the queue resource and see if that will help you instead.